# How to find the number of days in each month between two date in different years

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to get the number of day between two days but per each month.
I found some answers but I can't figure out how to do it when the dates have two different years.

For example, I have this dataframe:

```
df = {'Id': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
      'Item': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
        'StartDate': ['2019-12-10', '2019-12-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-05-10', '2019-03-10'],
        'EndDate': ['2020-01-30' ,'2020-02-02','2020-03-03','2020-03-03','2020-02-02']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['Id', 'Item','StartDate','EndDate'])
```

And I want to get this dataframe:

[image: Expected O/P:]

Comment: Do we have to dynamically generate the month columns, or do we already know the fixed range of start and end dates?

Comment: Good question, sorry for not be clear about that point. The idea is create the columns dynamically.

Comment: Can you supply the output dataframe you want but not as an image? as a code or text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
s = (df[["StartDate", "EndDate"]]
       .apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row.StartDate, row.EndDate), axis=1)
       .explode())

new = (s.groupby([s.index, s.dt.year, s.dt.month])
        .count()
        .unstack(level=[1, 2], fill_value=0))

new.columns = new.columns.map(lambda c: f"{c[0]}-{str(c[1]).zfill(2)}")
new = new.sort_index(axis="columns")
```

- get all the dates in between StartDate and EndDate per row, and explode that list of dates to their own rows
- group by the row id, year and month & count records
- unstack the year & month identifier to be on the columns side as a multiindex
- join that year & month values with a hypen in between (also zerofill months, e.g., 03)
- lastly sort the year-month pairs on columns

to get

```py
>>> new

   2019-11  2019-12  2020-01  2020-02  2020-03
0        0       22       30        0        0
1        0       31       31        2        0
2        0       31       31       29        3
3       21       31       31       29        3
4        9       31       31        2        0
```